# .htaccess url rewriting not-fix

Tags: .htaccess, key-value, window.location

By using jQuery I have sent a POST value to another file using window.location

where bname refers to some name from database

```
$.form(window.location + "?rt=" + bname,{project:project,bname:bname},'POST').submit();
```

after jQuery execution the following url appears on screen: `/m/?rt=Jaypee%20Group`

However I need the above one as `/m/JaypeeGroup`

I have tried htaccess rewrite but can't fix this issue

Is there any other way (*"window.location + "?rt=" + bname"*) in jQuery or how can I fix this in htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need for htaccess, just replace the space in javascript :

```
$.form(window.location + "?rt=" + bname.replace(" ", ""),{project:project,bname:bname},'POST').submit();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the post, but what i need is not only remove space    the thing i need is  http://localhost/m/?rt=Jaypee%20Group to be look like http://localhost/m/JaypeeGroup

Comment: You create the link in the first place as `/m/JaypeeGroup`. In .htaccess, for _incoming_ URLs, you rewrite it to `/m/?rt=Jaypee%20Group` or whatever format your script needs. Now, translating `JaypeeGroup` to `Jaypee%20Group` is a bit of a problem, assuming that you could have many such terms possible. You might be able to split any camelCase `([a-z])([A-Z])` => `$1%20$2`, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Hi thanks once again Still not fixed!!!, the name **adithya** will change dynamically sometimes it will be **raj** accordingly, As per my knowledge .htaccess is used to redirect to some url when a some conditioned url occurs, in order this i will not be having folder name adithya or raj as well eg: if you search for barak in wikipedia  it results as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack  if you search for Barack Obama it results as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama  i need a result like this please help out

Answer (score 0):

Invoke JQuery as follows.

```
$.form(window.hostname+"/"+context+"/m/"+project+"/"+bname+"/","POST").submit();
```

and add htaccess rewrite as per your requirements.

```
yourhostname/context/m/(.*)/(.*)/ .......
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the post but still i have error like it shows like http://localhost/m/undefined/m/Ace,Group,   how come i rectify these, I am working on this since noon cant find perfect solution please suggest more

Comment: I have made up to something like this                      [link]http://localhost/m/?Aditya,Developers    but i need to change this as   [link]http://localhost/m/Aditya,Developers   without that **"?"** mark symbol **i.e.** query string symbol, if i pass value without **"?"** it refers to folder name Aditya,Developers and throws an error

Comment: Suppose your `project=Adithya` and `bname=Developer` form your url like `yourhostname/context/m/Adithya/Developer/` i.e. `'window.hostname+"/"+context+"/m/"+project+"/"+bname+"/"'` then you can have htaccess rewrite rule as `^context/m/(.*)/(.*)/ /actionpagepath?project=$1&bname=$2` and make  sure no other rule matches this rule.

Comment: Hi thanks once again Still not fixed!!!, the name adithya will change dynamically sometimes it will be raj accordingly, As per my knowledge .htaccess is used to redirect to some url when a some conditioned url occurs, in order this i will not be having folder name adithya or raj as well eg: if you search for barak in wikipedia it results as en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack if you search for Barack Obama it results as en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama i need a result like this please help out

Comment: It can be dynamic. `^context/m/(.*)/(.*)/` (.*) means it can be anything.

Comment: Yeah I knew these (.+) refers 1 or more (.*) refers to 0 or more. Do I need to have a folder structure as context/m/ or how the htaccess finds the context/m/ in my folder structure

Comment: it is not folder structure. `context` is your `application context`. `m` can refer to a `module` of your application. rest of the things will be the parameters you want to pass. There is no restriction on the url format. You can form url as per your requirement.